# Distribution of sum of discrete random variables and central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

> Let $X_1 , X_2,\ldots$ be iid random variables such that $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$. If $S_n=\sum X_i$  prove that:
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(S_n=k^2\text{ for some } k) =0$$ and find this limit:
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\ln P\left(\frac {S_n}{n}>t\right)}{n}$$

this is from the
"Theory of Probability and Random Processes" book and i try to find  the solution and apply central limit theorem then we have $\frac {S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to normal distribution (weak convergence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with some solutions, although they might be somewhat more complicated than necessary!

1. Let $\epsilon>0$. As mentioned, according to the standard CLT, $S_n/\sqrt{n} \stackrel{D}{\to}N(0,1)$.  Using this fact, choose $0<b$ so that, for all $n\ge N_0$, $P(S_n/\sqrt{n} > b ) < \epsilon$. Now, the probability of interest can be decomposed into two terms:

$P(S_n = k^2,\;\;\;\mbox{ for some k})=P(S_n = k^2,\;\;\;\mbox{ for some k}, \; S_n<b\sqrt{n})+P(S_n = k^2,\;\;\;\mbox{ for some k}, \; S_n>b\sqrt{n}).$

for $n>N_0$, the second term on the right hand side of the above equation is less than $\epsilon$.

Regarding the first term, note that the number of possible values $k^2$ such that $0 < k^2 < b\sqrt{n}$ is no more than $\sqrt{b}n^{1/4}$. The most likely single value that the random variable $S_n$ takes is zero, and $P(S_n=0) ={n \choose n/2}(1/2)^n.$ Using Stirlings formula to approximate the factorials in ${n \choose n/2}$ gives ${n \choose n/2} \le C2^n/\sqrt{n}$, which in turn gives $P(S_n=0) \le C1/\sqrt{n}$, where $C$ is an absolute constant. Since this is the most likely value

$P(S_n = k^2,\;\;\;\mbox{ for some k}, \; a\sqrt{n}<S_n<b\sqrt{n}) \le \mbox{ [number of terms]$\times$ [largest possible probability] }= \frac{C\sqrt{b}}{n^{1/4}}< \epsilon$

For $n$ sufficiently large, say $n \ge N_1$. Thus for $n \ge \max \{N_0,N_1\}$, $P(S_n = k^2,\;\;\;\mbox{ for some k}) < 2\epsilon$, completing the proof.

2. We want to evaluate

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log P(S_n/n > t)}{n}$

As $-n \le S_n \le n$, the limit is clearly not defined if $t>1$, and is always zero if $t<0$, so the interesting case is $t\in(0,1)$. Notice that $S_n/2 \stackrel{D}{=} B_n - n/2$, where $B_n$ is a Binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $1/2$.

Two ingredients I use here are:

a) Hoeffdings inequality: $P( B_n > (t+1/2)n) \le e^{-2t^2n}$

b) Tail bounds for the normal distribution: If $Z\sim N(0,1)$, $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}t}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}t^3})e^{-t^2/2} \le P(Z>t) \le  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}t}e^{-t^2/2}$

Now, by multiplying and dividing by $P(Z > t\sqrt{n})$ inside the logarithm,

$\frac{\log P(S_n/n > t)}{n}= \frac{1}{n}\log \left(\frac{P(S_n/n > t)}{P(Z > \sqrt{n}t)}\right) + \frac{\log P(Z> t\sqrt{n})}{n}.$

Note that $P(S_n/n > t)= P(B_n > (t/2 + 1/2)n) \le exp(-t^2n/2)$, using Hoeffdings inequality. With this and the tail bound for the normal distribution,

$
\frac{P(S_n/n > t)}{P(Z > \sqrt{n}t)} \le  \frac{exp(-t^2n/2)}{({1}/{\sqrt{2 \pi}t\sqrt{n}}-{1}/{\sqrt{2 \pi}(t\sqrt{n})^3})exp(-t^2n/2) } =  \frac{1}{({1}/{\sqrt{2 \pi}t\sqrt{n}}-{1}/{\sqrt{2 \pi}(t\sqrt{n})^3}) }. 
$

Elementary arguments show that

$\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{({1}/{\sqrt{2 \pi}t\sqrt{n}}-{1}/{\sqrt{2 \pi}(t\sqrt{n})^3}) }\right) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, and so the limit of interest is governed by $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log P(Z> t\sqrt{n})}{n}.$ This limit is $-t^2/2$, which can be arrived at using L'Hopitals rule, or the same tail bounds for the normal distribution metioned above. Hence, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log P(S_n/n > t)}{n}=-t^2/2,$ $t\in (0,1)$.